# Not able to un-ignore GIT sub-directory

Tags: git, gitignore, subdirectory

Very simply I wish to unignore a sub-directory in an ignored directory.

My `.gitignore`:

```
app/migrations/
!app/migrations/config/Migrations/*
```

It does not work, if I remove the first line `app/migrations` is unignored, but the 2nd line is not working as expected. I have also tried:

```
!app/migrations/config/*
```

But it seems it is not possible to un-ignore?

**UPDATE**

It would appear to be a short-coming of GIT which does not not correctly support un-ignoring sub-directories. Surprising that such a standard tool is unable to support such a simple configuration whether it be an oversight or a bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+un-ignore+sub-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, and from the root `.gitignore` is the shortest sequence that will work *efficiently:*

```
app/migrations/*
!app/migrations/config
app/migrations/config/*
!app/migrations/config/Migrations
```

(It might be clearer and more explicit to write the second line as `!app/migrations/config/` but as long as `config` *is* a directory, the effect is the same.  See my additional remarks below.)

> In short you have to ignore then un-ignore each sub-directory.

That's correct, because when a *directory* is in fact ignored (by the last matching `.gitignore` rule), this gives Git permission to *omit scanning the directory entirely*.  As a result it never sees *any* of the files or sub-directories within that directory.  It is, however, very efficient: Git never needs to *open* the directory in the first place!  That's why this rule works the way it works.

> However this does not work 100% since app/migrations/config/* is un-ignored when it should only be app/migrations/config/Migrations.

That's because you said to do that.  Say to do what you mean, and you're OK. :-)

> What's more this is not only over-complicated but also makes for an almost unreadable and bloated git-ignore file - 6 lines just to un-ignore a sub-sub-directory.

Well, four lines.  That said, I do agree that this is overly complicated.  Git should recognize the pattern:

```
dir/*
!dir/sub/something
```

and automatically insert the appropriate `!dir/sub/`.  Likewise for:

```
dir/*
!dir/sub1/sub2/something
```

Here, Git could automatically insert the `!dir/sub1/` and `!dir/sub1/sub2/` rules as needed, with corresponding "ignore all files within" rules as needed.  These un-ignore insertions should end with `/` in case `dir/sub`, `dir/sub1`, and/or `dir/sub1/sub2` are files rather than directories.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the update, what I am trying to achieve is not properly supported, I can almost achieve what I want with:

```
app/migrations/
!app/migrations
app/migrations/config/
!app/migrations/config
app/migrations/config/Migrations/
!app/migrations/config/Migrations
```

In short you have to ignore then un-ignore each sub-directory. However this does not work 100% since app/migrations/config/* is un-ignored when it should omly be app/migrations/config/Migrations. What's more this is not only over-complicated but also makes for an almost unreadable and bloated git-ignore file - 6 lines just to un-ignore a sub-sub-directory.

Hopefully this will aid others who are tripped up by this limitation.

Answer (score -1):

According to Git docs:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

It is possible to achieve what you want if you un-ignore all folders up to the folder you want:

```
app/migrations/*

!app/migrations/config/*

app/migrations/config/*

!app/migrations/config/Migrations/*
```

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/2543566

Comment: Your answer also does not work. I can negate the first line with: app/migrations/*
!app/migrations/*, but if I add config !app/migrations/config/* it no longer un-ignores